# how to edit Data grids using PHP codeigniter and AJAX?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

for a system i want to edit the user directly on listing of users. See i have a page where i fetch all my users. Now A system may have many users so i dont want to open each user and edit him. instead i want to create a GUI using jquery or ajax that allows me to edit the user directly where i list him. I mean i click on user then it should turn into text box and let me edit the details and the saves the return. Following is my code where i fetch all the users :

```
<?php $this->load->view('admin/components/page_head') ?>
    <section class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">  <li class="active"> <h2><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>&nbsp Resellers&nbsp<span class="badge"><?php echo $this->db->count_all('reseller');?></span></h2></li></ul>


    <h3>    <?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/edit', '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add a Reseller'); ?></h3>

        <table class="table table-primary">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>SIP Userid</th>
                    <th>SIP Password</th>
                    <th>Unique ID</th>
                    <th>Allocation_block</th>
                    <th>Intial Users Required</th>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Country Code</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Balance</th>    
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    <?php if(count($users)): foreach($users as $user): ?>   
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/my_users/' . $user->id, $user->sip_username); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/edit/' . $user->id, $user->sip_password); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/edit/' . $user->id, $user->key); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/edit/' . $user->id, $user->allocation_block); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/edit/' . $user->id, $user->user_num); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/edit/' . $user->id, $user->name); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/edit/' . $user->id, $user->status); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/edit/' . $user->id, $user->country_code); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/edit/' . $user->id, $user->country); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/edit/' . $user->id, $user->email); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/edit/' . $user->id, $user->phone); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/edit/' . $user->id, $user->balance); ?></td>


                <td><?php echo btn_edit('admin/reseller/edit/' . $user->id); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo btn_delete('admin/reseller/delete/' . $user->id); ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">We could not find any users.</td>
            </tr>
    <?php endif; ?> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
    <?php $this->load->view('admin/components/page_tail') ?>
```

Comment: something like https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

Comment: Yes but its paid i think can you give me some other example @Vanojx1

Comment: @Vanojx1 Can You explain how i could use that using PHP Codeiginter or Just native PHP? i am nil in ajax :(

Comment: An editable grid is something that need some jquery for the frontend, you cant do it with only php.... php can be good to manage data changes in server side. i can suggest you this other plugin https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid but its jquery based